# Recommposition is not happening when I update a MutableStateFlow<List<AttendanceState>>

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow, compose-recomposition

I have a `MutableStateFlow<List<AttendanceState>>`,

```
var attendanceStates = MutableStateFlow<List<AttendanceState>>(arrayListOf())
    private set
```

My AttendanceState data class.

```
data class AttendanceState (
    var memberId: Int,
    var memberName: String = "",
    var isPresent: Boolean = false,
    var leaveApplied: Boolean = false
)
```

The list is rendered by a `LazyColumn`

The `LazyColumn` contains `Checkboxes`.
If i update the checkbox, the event is propagated to the `ViewModel` and from there I'm changing the value in the list

```
attendanceStates.value[event.index].copy(leaveApplied = event.hasApplied)
attendanceStates.value = attendanceStates.value.toList()
```

But this is not updating the `LazyColumn`.

Snippet of my implementation:

```
val attendances by viewModel.attendanceStates.collectAsState()

LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(top = 24.dp)) {
        Log.e("Attendance","Lazy Column Recomposition")
        items(attendances.size) { index ->
            AttendanceCheckBox(attendanceState = attendances[index], modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(horizontal = 16.dp), onAttendanceStatusChangeListener = { viewModel.onEvent(AttendanceEvent.IsPresentStatusChanged(index, it)) }, onLeaveAppliedStatusChangeListener = { viewModel.onEvent(AttendanceEvent.IsLeaveAppliedStatusChanged(index, it)) })
        }
    }
```

`Re-composition` is not happening.

Comment: From Compose's standpoint, the list is not changing. Some object inside of that list is changing, and nothing can observe that. Replace your `var` properties in `AttendanceState` with `val`. Emit a new immutable list that contains the new data (old `AttendanceState` objects except for one replaced with a new `AttendanceState` with the mutated data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend `SnapshotStateList` instead of a standard `List`, this will guarantee an update without having to create a new  instance of it like what you would do with an ordinary `List`, assuming you call `AttendanceState` instance `copy()` and updating at least one of its properties with a **different** **value**.

```
var attendanceStates = MutableStateFlow<SnapshotStateList>(mutableStateListOf())
    private set
```

I would also recommend changing the way you use your `LazyColumn` where items are mapped by their `keys` not just by their `index` position,

```
LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(top = 24.dp)) {
        items(attendances, key = {it.memberId}) {
               AttendanceCheckBox(...)
        }
}
```

and if you still need the `index` position.

```
LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(top = 24.dp)) {
       itemsIndexed(attendances, key = { index, item ->   
              item.memberId
       }) { item, index ->
              AttendanceCheckBox(...)
       }
}
```

You should also use `update` when updating your `StateFlow` instead of modifying its `value` directly to make it concurrently safe.

```
attendanceStates.update { list ->
      val idx = event.idx
      list[idx] = list[idx].copy(leaveApplied = event.hasApplied)
      list
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    val helper = ArrayList(attendanceStates.value)
    helper[event.index] = helper[event.index].copy(leaveApplied = event.hasApplied)
    attendanceStates.emit(helper)
}
```

Changing an item's properties will not trigger a `StateFlow`, you have to replace the whole item with the changed item and emit a new list.